# How To Get Day Based Graph Data From Time Based Data Structure

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql

I have pretty simple data and count value and want to show our user sum of count values as graph based on days.

We haven't decided where and how we will keep the data, so we are open to any suggestions.

This is my sample data for today (1 December)

```
{
“day” : 01.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 1,
“count”: 1
},
{
“day” : 01.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 14,
“count”: 8
}
```

We can easily query this data and convert it to

```
{
“day” : 01.12,
"total": 9
}
```

However, we have another data with uniq_id 15 created a few days ago.

{
“day” : 30.11,
“data_uniq_id” : 15,
“count”: 80
}

This data may be old but it is the latest data related to data_uniq_id 15. So we want to add count value to each query until today.

So new graph data must be:

```
  {
    “day” : 01.12,
    "total": 89
  }
```

More detail sample with a real data

```
{
“day” : 01.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 1,
“count”: 1
},
{
“day” : 01.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 13,
“count”: 8
},
{
“day” : 30.11,
“data_uniq_id” : 13,
“count”: 1
},
{
“day” : 29.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 18
“count”: 1
},
{
“day” : 29.12,
“data_uniq_id” : 1
“count”: 100
}
```

Graph data must be:

```
{
“day” : 29.12,
"total": 101
}, {
“day” : 30.12,
"total": 102 # added data_uniq 13 at 30.11
}, {
“day” : 31.12,
"total": 102 # no changes
}, {
“day” : 01.12,
"total": 120 # data_uniq_id 13 overwritten with day 1.12
}
```

Again we can change any type of data, use any databased to make this queries efficient.

Thank you.